# How to load data from SQL Server to SAP BW using SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2005, odbc, etl, sap-bw

I would like to load data from SQL server to SAP BW using SSIS.

Could someone help me on it, how can I do it?

Currently I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: You're asking a very broad question, can you be more precise? What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? What errors or other issues do you have?

Comment: Yeah, Actually i need to load the data from sql server database to SAP BW Using SSIS. For that i would like to create a SSIS Package. 

Source: SQL Server(OLEDB Source)
Destination: SAP BW

Comment: You seem to be asking "how do I create an SSIS package?", which is not something that can be answered in a short, definite way. I suggest you review the documentation and look for some [tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx), then just start building your package and see what happens. If you get stuck and have specific, answerable problems then of course you can post them here.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any links?

Comment: And Where can download the Data Provider for SAP (SQL Server 2005)

Comment: I already provided one link to a package tutorial but I have no idea where to download the provider; I assume SAP has it on their website.

Comment: using the sap bw provider i can able to connect to sql server dit still i am getting errors.....

Requested collection (data types) is not defined.(system.data).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move SQL Server Database data to SAP BW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54067226/move-sql-server-database-data-to-sap-bw)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use SSIS for that?
I would recommend either load using SAP BW standard anyDB source system or using BO Data Services.
Both do it natively and well.
If you insist, look at:
https://theobald-software.com/en/xtract-is-productinfo.html
They have the following feature:

### Xtract IS BW Loader

> With the Xtract IS BW Loader data target, you can reroute data streams within your SSIS data flow directly in your SAP BW system.
>
> The corresponding BW InfoPackage is automatically triggered and filled in.
> Of course, the component is based exclusively on the required SAP standard (staging BAPIs for third-party vendors).
> The following screenshot shows how the pipeline elements can be linked within the Integration Services with the transfer structure.