# Move SQL Server Database data to SAP BW

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, data-warehouse, sap-bw

I have read a few articles about moving data out of SAP BW and into SQL Server. I cant find any articles on moving the data from SQL Server to SAP BW, is it even possible and if so what would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*After searching on this topic, i found many link addressing this issue, in this answer i will try to summarize them all and to provide all links that can help you achieving your goal.*

There are many way to import data from SQL Server into SAP BW:

## (1) SAP BW DB Connect

> With DB Connect, you can load data from a database system that is supported by SAP, by
>
> - linking a database to the BW as a source system, thereby creating a direct point of access to external relational database management systems (RDBMS).
> - Making metadata known to BW by generating a DataSource.

- [Transferring Data Using DB Connect](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/58/54f9c1562d104c9465dabd816f3f24/frameset.htm)
- [Create DataSource for DB Connect step by step](https://blogs.sap.com/2010/05/25/create-datasource-for-db-connect-step-by-step/)
- [SAP BW 7.3: How to extract data from SQL Server using DB Connect](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/11/15/sap-bw-73-how-to-extract-data-from-sql-server-using-db-connect/)
- [Note 512739 - BW external DB Connect for MS SQLServer](https://www.stechno.net/sap-notes.html?id=512739)

## (2) SAP BO Services

- [Creating a Data Store by using SQL Server Database](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/11/20/creating-a-data-store-by-using-sql-server-database/)

## (3) SSIS - Microsoft Connector for SAP BW

Microsoft has created a SSIS connector for SAP BW, which allows you to create connection To SAP BW, you can refer to the following links and official documentations:

- [How to load data into SAP BW 7.3 from SQL Server using SSIS](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3814278)

**SQL Server 2016**

> The Microsoft Connector for SAP BW consists of a set of three components that let you extract data from, or load data into, an SAP Netweaver BW version 7 system.
>   The Microsoft Connector for SAP BW for SQL Server 2016 is a component of the SQL Server 2016 Feature Pack.

- [Microsoft Connector for SAP BW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/microsoft-connector-for-sap-bw?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Microsoft Connector for SAP BW Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/microsoft-connector-for-sap-bw-components?view=sql-server-2017)

**SQL Server 2014**

> The Microsoft Connector 1.1 for SAP BW consists of a set of three components that let you extract data from, or load data into, an SAP Netweaver BW version 7 system.

- [Microsoft Connector 1.1 for SAP BW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/microsoft-connector-for-sap-bw?view=sql-server-2014)

**SQL Server 2008**

- [Using SQL Server 2008 Integration Services with SAP BI 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd299430(v=sql.100))

If you decide to go with SSIS, I found this white paper from SAP that contains a detailed tutorials:

- [How to use Microsoft Connector 1.0 in
  MS SQL Server Integration Services packages with Open Hub services to export data from SAP BI to MS SQL](https://archive.sap.com/kmuuid2/80327e29-6521-2e10-0b9d-b9586a10c0ce/How%20to%20use%20Microsoft%20Connector%201.0%20in%20MS%20SQL%20Server%20Integration%20Services%20Packages%20with%20Open%20Hub%20Services%20to%20Export%20Data%20from%20SAP%20BI%20to%20MS%20SQL)

If this article didn't help, you can refer to tens of tutorials on how to create SSIS packages on the internet:

- [Steps to Create your First SSIS Package](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/218914/%2FArticles%2F218914%2FSteps-to-Create-your-First-SSIS-Package)
- [SSIS Basics: Setting Up Your Initial Package](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-setting-up-your-initial-package/)
- [Create a new SSIS package/](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/207/creating-a-simple-ssis-package/)
- [Official integration services tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-tutorials?view=sql-server-2017)

## (4) SSIS - Xtract IS BW Loader

This is a third-party tool created to allow SSIS to connect with SAP BW.

> The Xtract IS Component Suite offers nine components to provide all kinds of SAP interface technologies. Implement your data flows in a secure and type-safe way with a graphical editor.

- [Xtract IS – Plug’n’Play for SAP and SQL Server Integration Services](https://theobald-software.com/en/xtract-is/)

---

## Discussion

While searching for this issue, using SSIS to achieve that is not recommended because it may encounter some incompatibility issue, they recommended to use *SAP BW standard anyDB source system* or *SAP BO Data services*.

*Issues example:*

- [Loading Data from SSIS to SAP BW](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Community/Loading+Data+from+SSIS+to+SAP+BW)
- [Using SSIS to load data from SQL Server to SAP BW](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Using-SSIS-to-load-data-from-SQL-Server-to-SAP-BW)
- [SAP BW to SQl Server import and export wizard](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/38059eee-fbab-4d9f-8e11-77c562d57bee/sap-bw-to-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

On the other hand, SSIS guarantee the ease of use and there is thousands of topics and references for this technologies which will help you to achieve your goal faster than other technologies.

---

## References and external links

- [How to load data from SQL Server to SAP BW using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910582/how-to-load-data-from-sql-server-to-sap-bw-using-ssis/42307550)
- [Quick Tip: SSIS and SAP BW](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlmanofmystery/2012/11/15/quick-tip-ssis-and-sap-bw/)
  -[Setting up connection between SAP BW and SSIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f4d964d7-4f78-414f-a693-dbf15fa05733/setting-up-connection-between-sap-bw-and-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [White paper - SAP BW transferring data with DB Connect](http://www.ittestpapers.com/1/doc_view/979-sap-bw-transferring-data-with-db-connect.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the easiest way would be to use an [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool to extract data from MSSQL and insert into BW; specifically Microsoft's [Integration Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017) (SSIS), which you likely already have with your SQL Server license.

SSIS is a visual tool specifically designed for ETL scenarios like what you described, and is easy to get started with, I'm guessing that [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-how-to-create-an-etl-package?view=sql-server-2017) covers 90% of what you'll need to do.

However, you should also investigate if your license allows you to use the [SSIS connector for SAP BW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/sap-bw-connection-manager?view=sql-server-2017) and test if it is a viable option to simplify writing to BW, as writing directly to BW's tables may not be an option (e.g. because of licensing restrictions and/or technical impact due to directly manipulating a closed system's database).

Answer (score 0):

create the universe/ presentation layer using existing SQL Server DB. if there is no major transformation required ETL can be avoided